# Azure DevOps Notifications Force to Specify a Filter

Tags: azure-devops

I want to setup a notification whenever there is a release. I was able to do that before, but now I couldn't set this up for a different project. I don't know if there was something changed in Azure DevOps or I messed up myself.

Azure tells me to specify a valid filter but I don't have anything to filter. I can't remove the filter by clicking on the red X button. Please see the screenshot.

I read [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-team-group-global-organization-notifications?view=azure-devops) and it tells me that filter criteria are optional. See number 8 under "Create an email subscription" in the document.

[image: Azure DevOps Notifications - New Subscription]

Comment: I'd recommend you raise this as a bug on the [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html).  I just tried in Azure DevOps Server 2020 and the filter is not a requirement.  I imagine it has broken somewhat recently.

Comment: I just reported the issue to them https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1218059/azure-devops-notifications-force-to-specify-a-filt.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, this is strange. As a workaround you may use totally ridiculous condition like the one below:

[image]

Comment: I guess Microsoft deployed these filters without testing. Whatever condition you add here, it is not checked. DevOps will keep sending notifications even if you change operator to "Contains" in the condition in this screen shot.